# is it possible to use the origin SimplePagerButton image?

Tags: gwt

I want to make the last page button of SimplePager widget shown, but I found the constructor force us to use SimplePager.Resources as follow:
    SimplePager(SimplePager.TextLocation location, SimplePager.Resources resources, boolean   showFastForwardButton, int fastForwardRows, boolean showLastPageButton)

I try to copy the simplepager button in webpage and save it as gif or jpg, but I found the image cannot be saved. So is it possible to use the SimplePager button images to create a SimplePager with the last page button enabled?

I am using GWT 
2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimplePager(SimplePager.TextLocation location, SimplePager.Resources resources, 
    boolean showFastForwardButton, int fastForwardRows, boolean showLastPageButton)
```

Here's an example.

```
SimplePager pager = new SimplePager(
    TextLocation.CENTER, 
    GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class),
    false,
    0
    true);
```

or:

```
SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
SimplePager pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: thanks, it fix the problem, anyway, from the api, SimplePager.Resources is an interface, why we can .class it and then GWT.create it?